# Нужна ли запятая? 3

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Является ли здесь "по современным меркам" вводным?

По современным меркам (,) 25 лет – это много.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словосочетание "по современным меркам" соответствует **тематике вводных слов**, его значение ― "с точки зрения современности". Но как и почти все вводные слова, это сочетание может быть обособлено на правах вводного слова, а может являться необособленным обстоятельством.

Соответственно,  очень важна **структура предложения и позиция оборота**: необособленный оборот должен вписываться в структуру предложения, в противном же случае его лучше обособить.

Мне кажется, что обособленный вариант (с паузой при чтении) в заданном предложении  более уместен: **По современным меркам, 25 лет – это много.**

В Нацкорпусе можно встретить оба варианта: http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%20%F1%EE%E2%F0%E5%EC%E5%ED%ED%FB%EC%20%EC%E5%F0%EA%E0%EC&p=2

Comment: Спасибо большое!